# Merge text values with LEFT JOIN in one column and replace NULL with pre-defined wording

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables which you can also find in the `sql fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c41d2d/3):

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    Sales_Date DATE,
    Product TEXT,
    Sales_Channel TEXT,
    Sales_Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Sales
(Sales_Date, Product, Sales_Channel, Sales_Quantity)
VALUES 
("2017-05-23", "Product A", "Online", "400"),
("2018-09-10", "Product A", "Store", "200"),
("2018-12-14", "Product B", "Store", "600"),
("2019-01-03", "Product B", "Store", "700"),
("2019-02-15", "Product B", "Online", "650"),
("2019-03-20", "Product A", "Online", "380"),
("2019-08-25", "Product C", "TradeFair", "120"),
("2019-09-16", "Product C", "Online", "470"),
("2019-09-16", "Product A", "Store", "920"),
("2019-10-20", "Product B", "TradeFair", "860"),
("2020-01-03", "Product B", "TradeFair", "610");


CREATE TABLE Purchasing (
    Purchasing_Date VARCHAR(255),
    Product TEXT,
    Purchasing_Channel TEXT,
    Purchasing_Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Purchasing
(Purchasing_Date, Product, Purchasing_Channel, Purchasing_Quantity)
VALUES 
("2017-01-10", "Product A", "Local_Supplier", "1000"),
("2017-01-16", "Product A", "Local_Supplier", "3000"),
("2018-05-14", "Product C", "Foreign_Import", "1800"),
("2019-04-16", "Product C", "Foreign_Import", "2300");
```

I use the following query to connect the `Sales_Channel` and the `Purchasing_Channel` in one column:

```
SELECT
s.Sales_Date, 
s.Product, 
concat(s.Sales_Channel, '_', p.Purchasing_Channel) as Chanel,
s.Sales_Quantity
FROM Sales s
LEFT JOIN Purchasing p ON p.Product = s.Product
```

All this works fine so far.

---

As you can see in the tables above for `Product B` there is no `Purchasing_Channel`. 
Therefore, `Product B` is listed as `(NULL)`.

However, I want that the `(NULL)` is replaced by the wording `Sales_Channel` + `NoPurchasingChannel`. 
In the end the result should look like this:

```
Sales_Date   Product      Channel                             Sales_Quantity
2017-05-23   Product A    Online_Local_Supplier                400 
2018-09-10   Product A    Store_Local_Supplier                 200
2018-12-14   Product B    Store_NoPurchasingChannel            600
2019-01-03   Product B    Store_NoPurchasingChannel            700
2019-02-12   Product B    Store_NoPurchasingChannel            650
2019-03-20   Product A    Online_Local_Supplier                380
:            :            :                                    :
:            :            :                                    :
:            :            :                                    :
```

What do I need to change in my query to make it work?

Comment: Can we have the complete result, without the `':'`?

Comment: If you run the query in the sql fiddle you can see the complete result. Just replace the NULL by Sales_Channel + NoPurchasingChannel.

Comment: Go on. Edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to replace a `NULL` value by something else such as :

```
SELECT ...
...
concat(s.Sales_Channel, '_', IFNULL(p.Purchasing_Channel, 'NoPurchasingChannel')) as Chanel,
...
```

[working fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c41d2d/12)

Comment: Can also use 'coalesce' function in the same way

Answer (score 1):

```
MariaDB [so]> SELECT s.Sales_Date,  s.Product,  concat(s.Sales_Channel, '_', IFNULL(p.Purchasing_Channel,'NoPurchasingChannel')) as Channel, s.Sales_Quantity FROM Sales s LEFT JOIN Purchasing p ON p.Product = s.Product;
+------------+-----------+-------------------------------+----------------+
| Sales_Date | Product   | Channel                       | Sales_Quantity |
+------------+-----------+-------------------------------+----------------+
| 2017-05-23 | Product A | Online_Local_Supplier         | 400            |
| 2018-09-10 | Product A | Store_Local_Supplier          | 200            |
| 2019-03-20 | Product A | Online_Local_Supplier         | 380            |
| 2019-09-16 | Product A | Store_Local_Supplier          | 920            |
| 2017-05-23 | Product A | Online_Local_Supplier         | 400            |
| 2018-09-10 | Product A | Store_Local_Supplier          | 200            |
| 2019-03-20 | Product A | Online_Local_Supplier         | 380            |
| 2019-09-16 | Product A | Store_Local_Supplier          | 920            |
| 2019-08-25 | Product C | TradeFair_Foreign_Import      | 120            |
| 2019-09-16 | Product C | Online_Foreign_Import         | 470            |
| 2019-08-25 | Product C | TradeFair_Foreign_Import      | 120            |
| 2019-09-16 | Product C | Online_Foreign_Import         | 470            |
| 2018-12-14 | Product B | Store_NoPurchasingChannel     | 600            |
| 2019-01-03 | Product B | Store_NoPurchasingChannel     | 700            |
| 2019-02-15 | Product B | Online_NoPurchasingChannel    | 650            |
| 2019-10-20 | Product B | TradeFair_NoPurchasingChannel | 860            |
| 2020-01-03 | Product B | TradeFair_NoPurchasingChannel | 610            |
+------------+-----------+-------------------------------+----------------+
17 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat_ws()`:

```
concat_ws('_', s.Sales_Channel, p.Purchasing_Channel) as Chanel,
```

This ignores `NULL` values and doesn't include the `_`.  If you actually do want the underscore if one value is missing, use `coalesce()`:

```
concat_ws(coalesce(s.Sales_Channel, ''), '_', coalesce(p.Purchasing_Channel, '')) as Chanel,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
s.Sales_Date, 
s.Product, 
concat(COALESCE(s.Sales_Channel,'sales_channel'), '_', COALESCE(p.Purchasing_Channel,'purchasing_channel')) as Chanel,
s.Sales_Quantity
FROM Sales s
LEFT JOIN Purchasing p ON p.Product = s.Product
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try with below SQL query:

```
SELECT
s.Sales_Date, 
s.Product, 
concat(s.Sales_Channel, '_', IFNULL(p.Purchasing_Channel, 'NoPurchasingChannel')) as Chanel,
s.Sales_Quantity
FROM Sales s
LEFT JOIN Purchasing p ON p.Product = s.Product
```